# Is it possible to get a higher resolution from getDrawingCache?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-imageview, android-view

I am using SubsamplingScaleImageView by Dave Morrissey (https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) to allow users to crop and pan a photo with gestures.

I modified the library to add a tint and a logo to the photo. Now I need to upload the photo to the server. In order to do that I need to somehow extract the photo from the SubsamplingScaleImageView.

I added the following method to the SubsamplingScaleImageView class:

> ```
> /**
>  * Capture a photo of the image view
>  */
> public Bitmap getOutput() {
>     buildDrawingCache();
>     Bitmap b1 = getDrawingCache();
>     Bitmap b = b1.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
>     destroyDrawingCache();
>     return b;
> }
> ```

I am using this method to get the file, resize it to a specific resolution (800x800), and save it to my app's folder.

The problem I noticed is that the extracted photo from the drawing cache depends on the resolution of the device. For example, on my Full HD device I get 1080x1080 photo, which is enough, but on some lower res devices I get resolutions like 480x480 and that is not enough since the image needs to be bigger than that, so the photo gets blurry when I resize it to 800x800.

Is there a way to get the same resolution photo from that image view on all devices?